# how to make the end of a curve round like a semisphere?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry, curve-modifier

how to make the end of a curve round? (like pictured in the image? could it end somehow on a 'semisphere?)

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuCVcg9UfOA this is a good solution

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Vagabonk's comment, that's a neat method, but it does depend on Catmull-Clark's approximation of a square subdividing  as a circle, which isn't perfect, and a level of subdivision you might not want.

Here's a GN group which will modify a given curve to round-capped bevel of itself, with set radius, U & V resolutions:

[image]

Improvements could include UV mapping in continuity with the caps.. that might be easier in Blender 3.3.

[image]

[image]